# Hide form when application is minimized

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-xe

I have a main form and a status form that I display when work is going on in my application. If the work is finished I just call `Hide` on the status form and the status form disappears.

My problem occurs when I minimize the main form whilst the wait form is visible. Then both forms are hidden which is what I want. However, if the work finishes whilst the main form is minimized then when I restore it, the status form is also restored, even though `Hide` has been called on it whilst minimized.

`Visible` seems to be `False` for the status form when the application is minimized and therefore calling `Hide` seems to have no effect (the help says it just sets `Visible` to `False`).

Are that observations correct? How is the form visibility restored when the application gets focus again? How can I hide my form while the application is minimized?

Comment: Overriding 'WndParent' in 'CreateParams' for this display form?

Comment: +1 sounds like you are doing something non standard with your window ownership

Comment: @David: No, this is how an empty VCL project works. Try it yourself!

Comment: @so how many forms are there and are any of them modal?

Comment: No modal forms needed to reproduce this. Just the main form and the status form. Status form has `fsStayOnTop` set. Main form controls are disabled using two windows messages while the status form is visible.

Comment: I now, finally, understand the problem, and have edited the question to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: @David - I sure hope you've got it right, as this is what I tried to provide an answer.

Answer (score 4):

`Visible` of the display form is indeed false and calling `Hide` does nothing when the application is minimized, because it is hidden by the application as part of the minimization mechanism.

Code calls [`ShowOwnedPopups`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633547%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with first 'False' as 'bShow' while the application is minimizing, and then with 'True' as 'bShow' while the application is restoring. Since the function shows all windows which was hidden by a previous call, changing visibility of a form 
in between has no effect.

Now, see this quote from the remarks section of the documentation of the function,

> if a pop-up window is hidden by using
>   the ShowWindow function, subsequently
>   calling ShowOwnedPopups with the fShow
>   parameter set to TRUE does not cause
>   the window to be shown

So, one solution can be to hide the form before the application hides it, so it won't get shown while restoring. But then we have to know if the display form is actually to be hidden or shown when we restore. This can be achieved by putting a property on the display form or with a global variable perhaps. In the below, 'ShouldBeVisible' is a hypothetical property that would return true if we are to display information:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  ..
  private
    procedure WMSysCommand(var Msg: TWMSysCommand); message WM_SYSCOMMAND;
  ...

procedure TForm1.WMSysCommand(var Msg: TWMSysCommand);
begin
  if (Msg.CmdType = SC_MINIMIZE) and Assigned(Form2) and Form2.Visible then
    Form2.Hide;
  inherited;
  if (Msg.CmdType = SC_RESTORE) and Assigned(Form2) and Form2.ShouldBeVisible then
    Form2.Show;
end;
```

Comment: +1 for the idea. One question: Does only the main form receive these events? I'um using these from multiple forms, so I would like to integrate the mechanism into the status form itself. Seems that this form does not receive the events though.

Comment: Just tried catching the events in the main form. Unfortunately, `SC_RESTORE` is not triggered for my main form when I bring the window back up on windows 7.

Comment: @Smasher - I find that a bit weird, the window should have been restored in response to a WM_SYSCOMMAND. I wonder if the window receives a message holding a variation on SC_RESTORE. Would you care to 'bitwise and' the wParam of the message with $FFF0 as explained in the remarks section of [WM_SYSCOMMAND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?  Would 'OnRestore' event of an 'ApplicationEvents' work?

Comment: yes, `Application.OnRestore` works as expected. `SC_MINIMIZE` does not trigger if you click on the task bar icon in windows 7 (which is effectively a minimize as well). See my answer for the solution that works for me. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I now use the following solution which works for me:

1. In `Application.OnRestore` restore event handler I call `StatusForm.NotifyRestored`. Status form is explicitly hidden if it should not be visible.
2. In my status form I keep track of visibility in a boolean field `FShouldDisplay`. This is set in methods `ShowStatusForm` and `HideStatusForm`.

---

```
procedure TMainForm.OnApplicationRestore(Sender : TObject);
begin
StatusForm.NotifyRestored;
end;

procedure TStatusForm.NotifyRestored;
begin
if not FShouldDisplay then
  ShowWindow(Handle, SW_HIDE);
end;

procedure TStatusForm.ShowStatusForm;
begin
FShouldDisplay := True;
Show;
end;

procedure TStatusForm.HideStatusForm;
begin
FShouldDisplay := False;
Hide;
end;
```

Comment: Since you solved the problem with an ApplicationEvents component, I wonder if the component would work on the status form itself..

Comment: @Sertac: you are right, that would save me the delegation part. Thanks, I'll try that.

Answer (score 2):

*Warning:* I am not 100 % sure that the following approach is safe.

If you don't need the same form object to be alive for the duration of the application's life (which you most likely do not), then you could try to disable the automatic creation of the popup form (Project/Options) and then create and show it by

```
Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);
Form2.Show;
```

and then free it by

```
Form2.Release;
```

This way the form cannot possibly be restored together with the main form.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's the only right way of doing things but quite a common one definitely. At least, that's the way most popups in our projects are dealt with.

Comment: Thanks! Since this dialog appears very often (most of the time for rather short intervals) I would prefer to create the form only once.

Comment: Maybe the status window could be a child of your main form? (In plain English: replace the `Form2` status window by a `TPanel` on your main form.)

Comment: The main form is not the only form that needs this form. Could be a modal dialog that displays it or a non-modal editor window.