# Hide fsStayOnTop form when main form minimizes / prevent automatic restore

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-2007

I have a main form and a status form similar to the [question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295317).  However, my status window's FormStyle is fsStayOnTop, which causes some odd behavior when I try and minimize the main form when the status window is showing.

When I minimize the main form, both forms are hidden as expected, but when the status form is done completing its tasks when it is minimized, the main form automatically restores itself and its minimize button no longer works (but maximize/restore/close all still work). The only way to get the minimize function to work again is to restart the application. If I set the FormStyle to anything else, everything works fine, but my application requires the status form to stay on top when it is visible.

Is there a reason why the main form automatically restores like this? Is there a way to fix this?

```
procedure ButtonClick(sender:TObject);
begin
  //Gather some data

  ShowStatusWindow; // sets status window to visible, does its work, 
                    // then sets invisible. (Usually visible for about 10 seconds)

  //Gather more data

  Windows.SendMessage(self.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, 0, 0); //Freeze the main form for 
                                                        //flickerless drawing
  // Handle everything that would cause a redraw
  Windows.SendMessage(self.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, 1, 0);  // thaw form
  RedrawWindow(self.Handle, 0, 0, RDW_ERASE or RDW_FRAME or RDW_INVALIDATE or RDW_ALLCHILDREN);
end;
```

Comment: Most plausible explanation is that you have some code that cause the main form to restore when work is finished.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz If the only thing I change is the formstyle to something like fsNormal, then it works fine and the window does not restore. It only restores and minimize stops working when I have the formstyle set to fsStayOnTop. No other code is different.

Comment: How can we duplicate this behavior?

Comment: I don't understand why you expect us to try to re-create the program from a wooly description. Back in the old days, my clients used to fax me data which I would type in, or read it out over the phone. Then I could help them. Nowadays we e-mail files. You can just paste an SSCCE into the question and we can get you the answer in a few minutes. Don't make this hard. It's really easy if you just give us the SSCCE.

Comment: I apologize, I am trying to create a small application to replicate the problem since the original source code to handle this is thousands of lines long. For some reason, in the small application (just 2 forms and one button click event to show the fsStayOnTop form long enough to minimize it before it completes), the problem does not occur. If it would help, I can outline what happens when the form is shown.

Comment: What would help is the SSCCE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only explanation I can come up with, is your application's `MainFormOnTaskbar` is set to false.

If this is the case, when your application is minimized, the main form is not actually minimized but hidden according to VCL's minimization mechanism. When you send a `WM_SETREDRAW` message with 'wParam' set to True, you're forcing the hidden (not minimized) main form's window to be shown.

At this stage the application is still minimized according to the VCL since it has never been restored. When you click the minimize button of the main form, VCL calls `TApplication.Minimize` and sees that the *application window* is already minimized and so returns without further action, hence the main form is not minimized.

Here's a simple sample that would duplicate the problem. Set `MainFormOnTaskbar` to false in project source. Run the application and then click the button:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.Minimize;
  SendMessage(Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, 1, 0);
  // ShowWindow(Handle, SW_SHOWNORMAL); // this will also do the same
end;
```

You won't be able to minimize the form after that.

To solve, you can check if the main form is visible f.i. before disabling drawing:

```
  if IsWindowVisible(Handle) then begin
    Windows.SendMessage(self.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, 0, 0);
    ...
```

Comment: I appreciate the help. You are correct. Removing the window freeze/thaw does make it so the form does not restore when minimized. Do you have any idea why it remains minimized though when the status form's style is set to fsNormal? Is there something special that happens (or doesn't happen) when the form is told to redraw in this case? Could it be due to an issue with StayOnTop and the OnTaskbar? Thank you.

Comment: @Evan - You're welcome. Actually no, I can't think of anything straight. Since you're observing a difference, obviously there's a relation. I recall in D2007 'Normalize/RestoreTopMosts' were broken but I can't tell if it has got anything to do with it. I think we'd really need a test case to see what's happening.